# If setTimeout function is an asynchronous function then is there a way to visualize merge Sort using it? If not, what's the alternative?

Tags: angular, typescript

Where exactly should I add `setTimeout` function in order to visualize it on my browser?

NOTE: the array values are bound to div as there widths in order to get visualized.
When I initiate the merge sort process, I see changes but for some reason the sorting stops.

This is only happening when I have a `setTimeout` function in use, the moment I remove the `setTimeout` function the array gets sorted and I even see the visualization on the browser screen, but it is immediate i.e. I don't see the merging at all.

Here is my merge sort code:

```
mergesort(low: number, high: number) {
  if (low < high) {
    var mid: number = Math.floor((low + high) / 2);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.mergesort(low, mid);
      this.mergesort(mid + 1, high);
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.mergee(low, mid, high);
    }, );

  }
}
mergee(l: number, m: number, r: number) {
  var i: number, j: number, k: number;
  var n1: number = m - l + 1;
  var n2: number = r - m;

  var L = [];
  var R = [];

  for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    L[i] = this.arr[l + i];
  for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
    R[j] = this.arr[m + 1 + j];

  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  k = l;
  while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
    if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
      this.arr[k] = L[i];
      i++;
    } else {
      this.arr[k] = R[j];
      j++;
    }
    k++;
  }
  while (i < n1) {
    this.arr[k] = L[i];
    i++;
    k++;
  }
  while (j < n2) {
    this.arr[k] = R[j];
    j++;
    k++;
  }
}
```

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56157185/) - it's about visualising a bubble sort. It might offer some hints, at least.

Comment: @VLAZ Bubble sort has swapping involved and i have figured out ,where exactly do we need to put the setTimeout()  in sorting algorithms which involve swapping. In merge sort there is no swapping involved , this makes  it even tougher to determine the exact flow, but thanks for the hint and also for editing my question. I will make sure that my grammar stays correct from next time, also english is not my first language,so sorry about that .