# Visualize a Bubble Sort

Tags: javascript, html, bubble-sort

I want to make a page where I can visualize the bubble sort technique
for example display the first operation in the bubble sort in first line, 2nd in second line.

User can put in the numbers and then he sees every 500ms for example each step the sort mechanism takes

Basically thats what I want to display:

```
Iteration 1: [5,3,1,4,6] → [3,5,1,4,6] → [3,1,5,4,6] → [3,1,4,5,6] → [3,1,4,5,6]
Iteration 2: [3,1,4,5,6] → [1,3,4,5,6] → [1,3,4,5,6] → [1,3,4,5,6] → [1,3,4,5,6]
Iteration 3: [1,3,4,5,6] → [1,3,4,5,6] → [1,3,4,5,6] → [1,3,4,5,6] → [1,3,4,5,6]
```

My brain melts ^^

Comment: And the problem/question is? Read how bubble sort works, implement it in JavaScript (or search the www for a pre-made solution) and if this works add a "delay" after each round. Displaying the actual content of the array shouldn't be that hard at the end.

Comment: [How to gradually style elements that are being (bubble) sorted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56157185)

Comment: This answer shows how to visualize bubble sort using a bar chart: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66304869/2358409

Answer (score 0):

So the `setTimeout(function, milliseconds)` function in JavaScript takes as a first Parameter a function which then will be executed every 'milliseconds' milliseconds.

In the function you will have to implement an algorithm, that solves one step of Bubble Sort to the array that it gets as a parameter. The next time the function gets called, you will have to make sure it gets the updated array.
You can probably think about your visualization too, just the plain array isn't pretty, maybe you can draw bars or something.