# Why setTimeout doesn't work in my bubble sort function (REACT)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I'm trying to visualize my bubble sort algorithm so I want the algorithm to wait 50ms to be able to visualize it. I tried with setTimeout and async functions but it doesn't work, when you remove the setTimeout function you can see the array sorted, when it is in the function just doesn't work.
The project has installed bootstap@next and popper.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';
import './App.css'

function App() {
    const [values, setValues] = useState([43,4,3,56,6,3,36,56,7,5,45,34,87,99,34]);
    const [render, setRender] = useState(false)

    function forceRender() {
        setRender(true)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(render) {
            setRender(false)
        }
    }, [render])

    function bubble(arr) {
        for(let j = 0, len = arr.length; j < len; j++) {
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                        let temp = arr[i + 1];
                        arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = temp;
                        setValues(arr);  
                    }, 50)       
                }
            }
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        bubble(values)
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        forceRender()
    }, [values])

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <div className="container">
                    <span className="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">React Sorting</span>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div className="container sorting-container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="sorting">
                        {
                            values.map(e => {
                                return (
                                    <div className="bar" style={{height: `${e}%`}}>
                                        <div className="bar-text">{e}</div>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Do you realize the loop keeps looping? It does not pause and wait for the timeout

Comment: Probably relevant: [How to gradually style elements that are being (bubble) sorted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56157185)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a LOT of issues with this piece of code which are preventing it from working.  To name a few:

- `forceRender()` function isn't necessary and doesn't work.
- `useEffect` is breaking some React hooks rules.  The function depends on both `bubble()` and `values` - any good IDE with a linter like ESLint will point out this issue and help guide you.  As a quick workaround and for simplicity, I've just moved `bubble()` inside, along with the setting of the initial array on mount, to avoid needing to get the current state of `values`.
- `for` loop in `bubble()` runs to completion, all `setTimeout` callbacks point to the same instance of `arr` which has run to completion (this is a variant of a classic JS interview question).  This is why it was never rerendering - because the values in `arr` had already run to their final state and didn't change.  In order to capture the state of the array at different points in time without making big changes to your original code, you can make a copy inside the block scope (see code below).
- the `setTimeout` milliseconds are all set to the same time, so they will run all at once.  I suspect you wanted to see the play-by-play progression, in which case you can make the time a function of `j` and `i` in the `for` loop - e.g. `50 * i * j`
- Elements returned in the JSX map function should have unique keys.  This is a runtime error that you should see in your console.
- I've also reduced duplicates in the array for simplicity, so it's easier for React to keep track of unique keys for child elements.

Working code snippet you can run, for reference:

```js
const { useEffect, useState, Fragment } = React;

function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
function bubble(arr) {
  // Note: this loop runs to completion before any setTimeout callbacks are run.
  for (let j = 0, len = arr.length - 1; j < len; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
        // Make a copy so the setTimeout below has a "snapshot" of the array at
        // this point in time.
        const arrCopy = [...arr];

        let temp = arrCopy[i + 1];
        arrCopy[i + 1] = arrCopy[i];
        arrCopy[i] = temp;

        arr = arrCopy;

        setTimeout(() => {
          setValues(arrCopy);
        }, 100 * i * j);
      }
    }
  }
}
bubble([43, 4, 3, 56, 6, 36, 7, 5, 45, 34, 87, 99]);
  }, []);

  return (
<Fragment>
  <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div className="container">
      <span className="navbar-brand mb-0 h1"> React Sorting </span>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div className="container sorting-container">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="sorting">
        {values.map((val) => {
          return (
            <div key={val} className="bar">
              <div className="bar-text"> {val} </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="root" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to promisify `setTimeout` and use `asyc` & `await` to synchronize the process.
Try this solution.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';
import './App.css'

function App() {
    const [values, setValues] = useState([43,4,3,56,6,3,36,56,7,5,45,34,87,99,34]);
    const [render, setRender] = useState(false)

    function forceRender() {
        setRender(true)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(render) {
            setRender(false)
        }
    }, [render])

    function later(delay) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            setTimeout(resolve, delay);
        });
    }

    async function bubble(arr) {
        for(let j = 0, len = arr.length; j < len; j++) {
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                    await later(50);
                    let temp = arr[i + 1];
                    arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = temp;
                    setValues(arr);    
                }
            }
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        bubble(values)
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        forceRender()
    }, [values])

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <div className="container">
                    <span className="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">React Sorting</span>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div className="container sorting-container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="sorting">
                        {
                            values.map(e => {
                                return (
                                    <div className="bar" style={{height: `${e}%`}}>
                                        <div className="bar-text">{e}</div>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I tried the same solution some minutes ago and still not working

Comment: Note that Promises (plus async/await, which uses Promises under the hood) are just a convention to make the code more readable.  In this case just switching from the setTimeout callback style to Promises doesn't solve the root problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout() is a non-blocking function, that is, it doesn't stop the program until it returns from the timeout.
What happens in your program is that the first iteration asks setTimeout to do the swap at 50ms from now, and immediately jumps to the next iteration which does the same, all of them setting up to run at 50ms later but not 50ms apart from eachother.

Apart from Prime's solution, you could use a variable, let's say `t = 50`, that increases by 50 every iteration when inside the `if` statement, and you pass the value of that variable `t` to setTimeout, this way you will ensure that each iteration will run it's element swap at least 50ms apart from eachother.

For example, please adapt to your code:

```
    let t = 50;

    function bubble(arr) {
        for(let j = 0, len = arr.length; j < len; j++) {
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                        let temp = arr[i + 1];
                        arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = temp;
                        setValues(arr);  
                    }, t)
                    t = t + 50;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```